# pgf plots, barplot, irregular spacing between bars/columns

Tags: pgfplots, scaling

I've created a (grouped) bar plot with three groups of bars/columns, but it would be great if the space between the first and the second group would be a bit larger than the space between the second and third group of bars. How can I reach this (that is, irregular x axis scaling)?

Update:

Well, I finally succeeded in solving my issue thanks to Jake, but now another problem has come up. Something is wrong with my nodes. Here is my code and attached the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}     
\definecolor{blue4a}{HTML}{4D79A3}
\definecolor{blue4b}{HTML}{5C8DBD}
\definecolor{blue4c}{HTML}{91ADD1}
\definecolor{blue4d}{HTML}{C3CFE2}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
name        2011    2012    2013    2014
Girls       10      20      30      40
Boys        20      30      40      50
Overall     60      70      80      90
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ylabel                  =   Percentage,
    label style             =   {font=\tiny\sffamily},
    axis lines*             =   left,                           
    tick align              =   outside,
    tick label style        =   {font=\tiny\sansmath\sffamily}, 
    x                       =   1.64cm,                         
    y                       =   0.055cm,                        
    ymin                    =   0,
    ymax                    =   98,
    ymajorgrids,                                                    
    grid style              =   dashed,
    ybar                    =   0.00cm,                         
    bar width               =   0.32cm,                     
    nodes near coords,                                      
    every node near coord%
    /.append style          =   {%
    font                    =   \tiny\sansmath\sffamily},   
    enlarge x limits=0.305,
    x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1+(#1==2)*0.25}},
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={data.dat}{name},
    xticklabel style={text height=2ex}
]

\addplot [fill=blue4a] table [x expr=\coordindex] {data.dat};
\addplot [fill=blue4b] table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=2] {data.dat};
\addplot [fill=blue4c] table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=3] {data.dat};
\addplot [fill=blue4d] table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=4] {data.dat};

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I didn't know the site could be accessed via Palantir. Please post some code showing what you have tried so far. This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Hi Saruman, welcome to the site! Take a look at [the answer to "How to add additional space for the last group of bars in gnuplot?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82438/2552), that looks like it might help you.

Comment: Hi Jake, your link definitely is a step in the right direction. ;) But I wonder how to apply this to my example (above). If someone knows, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. If you think you have solved your problem, please don't edit your question; instead, post an answer to your question. If you are having a new problem and it is not previously asked on this site, open a new question and let users think about it.

Comment: At least with PGFPlots v1.14 the `nodes near coords` are positioned directly above the bars, so I think as expected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP solved the first part himself and the follow-up question is most probably solved by updating PGFPlots.